# having the Div next to form in the same line

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the following code:

```
<div id="heroDiv">
            <form id="loginDiv">
                <h4>Log in</h4></br>
                <input id="username" autofocus="" name="username"  placeholder="Email address" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text"/></br></br>
                <input id="password" autofocus="" name="password"  placeholder="Password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="password"/></br></br>

                <div id="forgot">
                    <p><input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox"/> Remember me</p>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com"> Forgot password?</a></br>
                </div>

                <div id="signUp">
                    <p><button id="login">Log in</button> </br></br>                        
                    <p>Not a member yet? <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> Sign Up</a></p>
                </div>
                </br>
                <p id="name">© Biz Yapalım <span id="bottomLinks"> <a href="http:/www.google.com">Privacy</a> <a href="http://www.google.com"> Terms</a></span>

         </form>

        <div id="errorMessages">
                <p id="userErrorMessage">Email Error Message</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xkqxbqt/)

I want to make a div on the right side of the login form so that it

could display the error messages but I just can't figure it out, any suggestions?`

Thanks

Comment: Can you start by telling me why you're using `</br>` instead of `<br>`. Also, the relevant code should be in the question, not just somewhere else.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to web development and I thought that's the right way to do, I'll fix it right away, thanks!

Comment: I'm curious _why_ you thought it was the right thing to do. If there's a textbook somewhere that says using only an end tag for something is OK, I want to know what it is! In many cases, you can omit end tags, but you can never omit a start tag and use only an end tag. `br` doesn't even have an end tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, there are two different issues here:

- form, div, and paragraphs are breaking-line elements. It means that the content within it starts a new line. To avoid that behavior you can add the following property to the css, and ajust it to those different elements, per say:

```css
form, p, div { display: inline }
```

- the other issue comes from your using of *br*, *br* means break line, it does the same as above. If you wish to put space between two elements (which seems to be the case as you added br one after another) use margins and/or paddings of block elements such as divs or spans.